# AngularJs Application + Prerender with S3

Tags: angularjs, node.js, nginx, amazon-s3, prerender

I have an single page application, the server side is on node.JS. The AngularJS resources are hosted on S3 Bucket. I have an nginx server layer which proxies the node based api and static contents from S3 Bucket. I want to prerender the AngularJS app to serve the static content to search engines. I have changed the nginx.conf to use [prerender.io](https://prerender.io/), but the AngularJS app is not fully loaded. Anything inside "nv-view" is not getting loaded when I try to test the prerender snippet manually by using "_escaped_fragment_=". Following is the nginx.conf snippet:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/dev.log main;

    location /api/ {
        rewrite /api/(.*) /$1  break;
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-NginX-Proxy    true;
        proxy_connect_timeout      90;
        proxy_send_timeout         90;
        proxy_read_timeout         90;
        proxy_buffer_size          4k;
        proxy_buffers              4 32k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size    64k;
        proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;

        # websockets:
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

        client_max_body_size       30m;
        client_body_buffer_size    128k;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri @prerender;
    }

    location @prerender {
        #proxy_set_header X-Prerender-Token xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;

        set $prerender 0;
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "baiduspider|twitterbot|facebookexternalhit|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora link preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator") {
            set $prerender 1;
        }
        if ($args ~ "_escaped_fragment_") {
            set $prerender 1;
        }
        if ($http_user_agent ~ "Prerender") {
            set $prerender 0;
        }
        if ($uri ~ "\.(js|css|xml|less|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|pdf|doc|txt|ico|rss|zip|mp3|rar|exe|wmv|doc|avi|ppt|mpg|mpeg|tif|wav|mov|psd|ai|xls|mp4|m4a|swf|dat|dmg|iso|flv|m4v|torrent|ttf|woff)") {
            set $prerender 0;
        }

        #resolve using Google's DNS server to force DNS resolution and prevent caching of IPs
        resolver 8.8.8.8;

        if ($prerender = 1) {

            #setting prerender as a variable forces DNS resolution since nginx caches IPs and doesnt play well with load balancing
            set $prerender "service.prerender.io";
            rewrite .* /$scheme://XXX.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com$request_uri? break;
            proxy_pass http://$prerender;
        }
        if ($prerender = 0) {
            proxy_pass $scheme://XXX.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PhantomJS might be erroring out on something. Did you try running the Prerender server locally? Send me the URL you're testing and I'd be happy to test it out and see what's wrong! todd@prerender.io